# FATAL: no pg_hba.conf entry for host "****", user "xyz", database "***", SSL off

Tags: postgresql, pgadmin-4

I am trying to connect to postgresql but keep getting this error "FATAL: no pg_hba.conf entry for host "****", user "xyz", database "***", SSL off". I tried adding the host all all 0.0.0.0/0 md5 in pg_hba file and restarting the service. But it didn't help. I tried checking the port and opening it. But still facing the same issue.

Below is my config.

```
# TYPE  DATABASE        USER            ADDRESS                 METHOD

# IPv4 local connections:

host all all 0.0.0.0/0 md5
host  all  all 10.52.16.6/0 trust
host    all             all             127.0.0.1/32            md5
# IPv6 local connections:
host all all 0.0.0.0/0 md5
host  all  all 10.52.16.6/0 trust
host    all             all             ::1/128                 md5
# Allow replication connections from localhost, by a user with the
# replication privilege.
host all all 0.0.0.0/0 md5
host  all  all 10.52.16.6/0 trust
host    replication     all             127.0.0.1/32            md5
host    replication     all             ::1/128                 md5
```

Any help would be appriciated.

Comment: When you log in as a superuser, what do you get when you run: `SELECT * FROM pg_hba_file_rules;`

Comment: Are you certain you are using IPv4 when connecting by hostname you might be using IPv6? BTW when you get an error about pg_hba you are connected to the server so no need to check open port.

Answer (score 0):

```
SHOW hba_file;
```

run the command in psql, makesure you are editing the correct conf file